# The program started using TightVNC is displayed on the other desktop GUI environment

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, tightvncserver

I have TightVNC installed on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. I found that if I logged into Ubuntu Desktop (GUI environment), when I open “File Manager” application through VNC, the File Manager will open at the original Ubuntu Desktop and not show up on the remote VNC screen.
Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: How many monitor do you have in the remote computer?

Comment: Only one monitor.